# Databound Datagidview with Checkbox cannot b checked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that is bound to a database in SQL server and I put one checkbox on the first column and when I run the program, the checkbox cannot be checked.why is that? is the conflict between the database and the checkbox? pls. help I need it so badly. thank you

I tried setting the `datagridview` properties to `ReadOnly=true`, enable editing to true but none of these did not work

C# Winform codes:

```
private void dgvSummaryUnserviceable_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
    try
        {
            if (dgvSummaryUnserviceable.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Items to Load.Choose Transaction type first", "Field Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
            else
            {
                if (cboTranstype.Text == "PAR")
                {

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSummaryUnserviceable.Rows)
                    {

                        bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colUnserviceable"].Value);
                        if (isSelected)
                        {

                            //getting the specific cell value in datagridview
                            if (dgvSummaryUnserviceable.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                            {
                                emp_idno = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                                MessageBox.Show("" + emp_idno);
                                T_type = cboTranstype.Text;
                                prop_no = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                                qty = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[10].Value);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int iRows = dgvSummaryUnserviceable.Rows.Count;
                            int iCheckedCount = 0;

                            for (int i = 0; i < iRows; i++)
                            {
                                int iChecked = 0;
                                iChecked = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSummaryUnserviceable.Rows[i].Cells["colUnserviceable"].FormattedValue);
                                iCheckedCount += iChecked;
                            }//for

                            if (iCheckedCount == 0)
                            {

                                MessageBox.Show("Select first the Items you want to Transfer", "Field Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                                return;

                            }//if

                        }//else
                    }//foreach
                }//cboTranstype
            }//else
        }//try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Try Catch Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

here's my full code. the checkbox is not bound to database, i just added it on the design but i want to use it my selector of a particular record on the datagridview with some columns bound to database[screenshot for datagridview]

there's my screenshot.after the record has been loaded on the datagridview, i will click the checkbox but when i do, it cannot be checked.

[checkbox and datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtM1l.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196454/discussion-on-question-by-rommel-databound-datagidview-with-checkbox-cannot-b-ch).

Comment: In your logic to generate the checkboxes, how are you assigning a unique `id` to the checkbox? How will you use this value to perform your operation in your `DB`?

Answer (score 0):

If you Want to edit the data in datagridview then you need to set `Read-only` property is `false` and `Enable` property is `true` of datagridview.

You can set property three different layers
 1.full data gridview 
 2.on columns 
 3.on rows

In your case, if you want column 1 can edit reaming not edit then (on full datagridview `Readonly`= false) and then for remaining column make property true. like this

`dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;`

`dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;`

[More Info](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-readonly-column.htm)

Comment: @rommel  If my anwer help you then you can tick the answer as accepted